# Postgres privileges: psql \dp - what is about the plus-sign

Tags: postgresql, psql, debian

I used psql-command "\dp" to find out the given grants.

Versions on test-server: PostgreSQL 9.1.15 on armv7l-unknown-linux-gnueabi, compiled by gcc (Debian 4.6.3-14) 4.6.3, 32-bit

Out of the postgres-handbook:

```
rolename=xxxx -- privileges granted to a role
    =xxxx -- privileges granted to PUBLIC

        r -- SELECT ("read")
        w -- UPDATE ("write")
        a -- INSERT ("append")
        d -- DELETE
        D -- TRUNCATE
        x -- REFERENCES
        t -- TRIGGER
        X -- EXECUTE
        U -- USAGE
        C -- CREATE
        c -- CONNECT
        T -- TEMPORARY
  arwdDxt -- ALL PRIVILEGES (for tables, varies for other objects)
        * -- grant option for preceding privilege

    /yyyy -- role that granted this privilege
```

When I fire up the command there is an additional plus-sign at the end of the acl-column (right after postgres). I could not find any documentation about it.

```
postgres=# \dp test.*
                               Access privileges
 Schema | Name  | Type  |     Access privileges     | Column access privileges 
--------+-------+-------+---------------------------+--------------------------
 test   | films | table | postgres=arwdDxt/postgres+| code:                   +
        |       |       | =arwdDxt/postgres         |   candando=r/postgres
```

What is the plus sign about?

Comment: I quoted the relevant part I thought and I cannot find any hint to a "+" after the "role that granted this privilege".

Comment: Ah, you mean _that_ plus sign. I think that's just the indicator that the data spans more than one column. You'll get that with other multi-line values as well, not just the output of `\dp`

Comment: Oh man. You are right. I tried out with extended-display (\x) and there is no "+"-sign. Thanks alot.
The question is answered - Must I do anything to close it?

Comment: Either just delete the question or @a_horse_with_no_name could post his his comment as answer to accept. It seems like a trivial misunderstanding (as soon as you know it), but it might fool other people as well, so the question might not be useless.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That plus sign is the indicator that the data spans more than one column. You'll get that with other multi-line values as well, not just the output of `\dp`